# Can't SSH from my IP, but can from other IPs

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, denyhosts

I installed DenyHosts, which is a script intended to be run by Linux system administrators to help thwart SSH server attacks (also known as dictionary based attacks and brute force attacks).

It did not even finish installing and everyone connected to server got disconnected. I rebooted the server from the server control panel(Host).

I was able to webmin and other stuff like web and SSH from another IP using my phone's hotspot, but on my PC and other PCs at home I can't.

The package has been removed.

Now, how should I be able to SSH again from my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hosts.deny`, for example using

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts.deny
```

and remove the line with your IP address.

Comment: and make sure you restart/reload the sshd service after making the changes in hosts.deny